# How to find a field of an object using a Generic method?

Tags: java, generics, field

I have a Cube object with a public 'x' field. I have a toString method in my Cube class which prints out the x,y,z fields, but when I directly access it, I get an error where: **field cannot be resolved or is not a field**.

```
public <T> void setPosition(T object){
   System.out.println(object);  
   System.out.println(object.x); // error here
}
```

Comment: `T` can be any Object, so the compiler does not know if `x` is a field of it or not. If `T` were declared as extending some type (e.g. `public <T extends Point> ...`), and that type has a `x`, than that would have worked.

Comment: ^ that - the other way - if you know what types you can expect, is using X instanceof Y to check if its whats you expected and  then cast it.

Comment: Hmm, but say I have multiple classes that all have the same field so I know the field will be there (x,y,z), so shouldn't there be a way to be able to have a generic method that works with multiple classes with similar fields?

Comment: yes, if all these object have one parent or implement an interface that also declares that field/method. Or as Worthless wrote, using `instanceof` and casting.

Comment: Is the a good example of the parent way of doing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that I could access the field utilizing Reflection methods and cast to the object I needed. This is supported using an abstract class with this field so that all objects  inheriting from this object can utilize this function.

```
public <T> void setPosition(T object) {
   Field xField = object.getClass().getField("x");
   Field boxField = object.getClass().getField("boundBox");
   float xpos = (float)xField.get(object);
   BoundingBox box = (BoundingBox)boxField.get(object);
}
```

I'm open to critique, but this has been working very well with my multiple classes inheriting from my abstract base class. The reason for this method, is for another class to work with these other classes without creating multiple functions, thus giving flexibility for a user who wants to create their own classes inheriting from the abstract class.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend defining an interface that declares the method that your multiple different types will expose. Something like:

```
public interface ValueProducer {
  public String getValue();
}
```

Then, your `Cube` type would look like this:

```
public <T extends ValueProducer> void setPosition (T obj) {
   System.out.println(obj);  
   System.out.println(obj.getValue());
}
```

Then any type with which you wish to use this method need only implement the interface `ValueProducer`, and can still extend or implement whatever other types are appropriate for their use cases.

Or, you could omit generics altogether, and just pass `obj` in as a `ValueProducer`.

Comment: Would this work if I had several different class, like Cube, Sphere, etc. I basically want to use a generic function to pass in objects with the same fields, so I know they could inherit from a parent so would this parent be an interface or an abstract class?

Answer (score 1):

your method does not know what is the type `T`.

But we can say T is some class which extends

```
public class GenericCube {
    public String value;
    }
```

So, now we able to access the `value` because we know about it

```
public <T extends GenericCube> void setPosition(T obj){
    System.out.println(obj);
    System.out.println(obj.value);
}
```

Comment: still not sure if `GenericCube` should be generic? can be a bit confusing

Comment: sure. my mistake